# Wrong redirect when data have been submitted using if else laravel

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, redirect

I am trying to get a request from the input I just got where if the request input recommendation is No or KIV, it will redirect to home if not it will redirect to another page. But the problem now is that if the recommendation I put is Yes and some other things as No, it will redirect me to home instead of another page. Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot

```
    public function eval(Request $request){
     $Evaluation = new evaluation;
        $personal_info = new personal_info;
        $Evaluation->recommendation = $request->input('recommendation');
        $Evaluation->training_schedule = $request->input('training_schedule');
        $Evaluation->training_date = $request->input('training_date');
        $Evaluation->PortalLogin = $request->input('PortalLogin');
        $id = $request->user_id;
        $id= personal_info::find($id);
        $id->evaluations()->save($Evaluation);

        if(($Evaluation->recommendation = $request->input('recommendation')) == 'No' || 'KIV')
            return redirect('/home');
        else{
    return redirect(url('/user/showtest/'.$id->id.'/test) );
}
```

Comment: ($Evaluation->recommendation = $request->input('recommendation')) == 'No' || 'KIV' this will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They syntax of your "if statement" is incorrect. `|| 'Kiv'` this statement is evaluated alone and not against recommendation, so change the code to this way

```
$recommendation = $Evaluation->recommendation = $request->input('recommendation');

if( $recommendation == 'No' || $recommendation == 'KIV')
    return redirect('/home');
else {
    return redirect(url('/user/showtest/'.$id->id.'/test) );
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I made such a simple mistake, thank you so much for your help, just asking for the $recommendation if I just use $Evaluation->recommendation = $request->input('recommendation'); will it still work?

Comment: this might also work! if(($Evaluation->recommendation = $request->input('recommendation')) == 'No' || $Evaluation->recommendation == 'KIV')